# How to add multiple filters to a property in Search api Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, search-api

Below is my `querytext` to get items from pages library and document library.

```
$quertText="createdby:XXX AND contentclass:STS_ListItem_850 
AND STS_ListItem_DocumentLibrary"
```

But it is returning 0 results.

If I use any one of contentclass property it is showing results:

```
$quertText="createdby:XXX AND contentclass:STS_ListItem_850"
```

How can I use them together ?

Comment: use it as `$quertText="createdby:XXX AND contentclass:STS_ListItem_850 contentclass:STS_ListItem_DocumentLibrary "`

Comment: $queryText="createdby:xxx AND  contentclass:STS_ListItem_850 contentclass:STS_ListItem_DocumentLibrary" 0 results :-(

Comment: sorry i meant `$quertText="createdby:XXX contentclass:STS_ListItem_850 contentclass:STS_ListItem_DocumentLibrary "`

Comment: happy to help, have posted that as answer. Would request you to please accept it by ticking the checkmark besides the answer. This will help remove the question from the unanswered section ! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your code snippet as:

`$quertText="createdby:XXX contentclass:STS_ListItem_850 contentclass:STS_ListItem_DocumentLibrary"`

The KQL query will treat space as AND operation.

Reference - [(KQL) syntax reference](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/keyword-query-language-kql-syntax-reference)